# Data from local json is not displayed in a FlatList

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to display information from a local json file I have.
The json data does gets logged to the console, and seems fine, but I can't get it to display as a FlatList.

This is my json file:

```
{
"countries": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "code": "US",
        "display_name": "USA",
        "area_code": 123
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "FR",
        "display_name": "FRANCE",
        "area_code": 123
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "AUS",
        "display_name": "AUSTRALIA",
        "area_code": 123
    }
]
}
```

This is my FlatList:

```
//@ts-ignore
import CountryList from '../utils/countries.json';

const CountryPicker = () => {    
    return (
        <View style={pickerStyles.container}>
            <Text style={pickerStyles.title}>Pick your location</Text>
            
            <FlatList
                    data={CountryList}
                    //@ts-ignore
                    renderItem={CountryList.countries.map(country => {
                        return (
                            <Text>{country.display_name}</Text>
                        );
                    })}
                    keyExtractor={country => country.id}
                />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should do like below, as Data prop expects an array and you are passing an object.

```
     <FlatList
                data={CountryList.countries}
                //@ts-ignore
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return (
                        <Text>{item.display_name}</Text>
                    );
                })}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
```